# Tweet and sending it as a Post method

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a home page and a controller.  In the home page I have a text area where a user would enter a text and it needs to send it to the controller as  a post once the "Tweet" button is pressed.

Homepage:

```
<textarea action = "twit" method = "post" class="tweetbox" ></textarea>
                        <div class="row button">
                        <button class="btn btn-twitter" value =" add2" >
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"/>Tweet

                        </button>
```

This is the controller side:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
 HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException, IOException {



String url = "/home.jsp";
String action = request.getParameter("twit");
System.out.print(action);

if(action.equals("add2"))
{

    String email = request.getParameter("email");
String text = request.getParameter("text");

Twit twit = new Twit(email,text);
```

Comment: It is not working. Not sure what I am doing wrong.